# copy character string to an unsigned buffer: Segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, buffer, memmove

i am trying to copy two integers and a character string to a buffer and print the buffer elements out. I get a seg fault for the third printf statement:

```
    id = 102;
    len = 3;
    str = "working";
    memmove(buffer,&message_id,sizeof(id));
    memmove(buffer+(sizeof(id)),&len,sizeof(len));
    memmove(buffer+(2*sizeof(id)),&string, sizeof(str));

    printf("1 is: %d\n", buffer[0]);
    printf("2 is: %d\n", buffer[4]);
    printf("3 is %s\n, buffer[8])); // here is where i get the seg fault should
    be a string
    /***/
    bufer is declared as unsinged char buffer[444];
```

I dont know why this would seg fault?

Comment: what is buffer with two "f" declared as -- you say bufer is unsigned char[444]

Comment: How is *string* and *str* declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were several issues on your code, but the most important point is that `memmove()` does not copy the null character byte of the string.

> [The function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memmove/) does not check for any terminating null character in source - it always copies exactly num bytes.

This gives you two options:

- Account for that while you are copying the stuff:

`memmove(buffer+sizeof(id)+sizeof(len), str, strlen(str) +1);`

- Or after the memory was copied, make sure the string ends with a `'\0'` (aka. `0`) on your buffer:

`memmove(buffer+sizeof(id)+sizeof(len), str, strlen(str));`

`buffer[sizeof(id)+ sizeof(len) + strlen(str) + 1] = 0;`

Anyway, the code works now. Another issue was that you were trying to specify the length of the string with `sizeof(str)`. That's wrong, and you should be doing `strlen(str)`. One last thing, for clarity and security purposes don't do `2*sizeof(id)`. If later you decide to change the variable type you are screwed. The right way wold be `sizeof(id)+sizeof(len)`. That's all.

```
int id = 102;
int len = 3;
char* str = "working";
char buffer[444];

memmove(buffer,&id,sizeof(id));
memmove(buffer+(sizeof(id)), &len, sizeof(len));
memmove(buffer+sizeof(id)+sizeof(len), str, strlen(str));
buffer[sizeof(id)+ sizeof(len) + strlen(str) + 1] = 0;

printf("1 is: %d\n", buffer[0]);
printf("2 is: %d\n", buffer[4]);
printf("3 is: %s\n", &buffer[8]);
```

Comment: great explanation. THanks alot. i forgot to use strlen and account for the null character

Answer (score 4):

`buffer[8]` is a `char`, `%s` waits for string, meaning `char *`, pass `&buffer[8]` instead. You get segmentation fault because printf tries to treat a **char** as a **pointer to char**, which is address (and if a char is passed it's unlikely to be a valid one)

EDIT: as **David** commented, if the starting point for copying the string is related to the values before it, don't use a fixed value, instead of `&buffer[8]` use `buffer+(2*sizeof(id))` or `buffer[2*sizeof(id)]`

Comment: +1, although `buffer+8` or better yet `buffer+2*sizeof (int)` would be preferable

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you are trying to print the string by passing only a character.  This is because `buffer[8]` refers to the `char` at index 8, not the string starting at that position.  So you need to take the address of `buffer[8]` to make it a string or `char*`.

The reason why it segfaults is that `printf` attempts to print a string starting at the address given by the first char (ie. the string contents itself), which is not a valid pointer.

There are also number of typos and mistakes.  A working version is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char buffer[444];
    int id = 102;
    int len = 3;
    char* str = "working";

    memmove(buffer,&id,sizeof(id));
    memmove(buffer+(sizeof(id)),&len,sizeof(len));
    memmove(buffer+(2*sizeof(id)), str, sizeof(str));

    printf("1 is: %d\n", buffer[0]);
    printf("2 is: %d\n", buffer[4]);
    printf("3 is %s\n", &buffer[8]);

    return 0;
}
```

If you had compiled this app with all warnings enabled (ie. `-Wall`), your compiler (at least GCC does) should warn you about your mistake like this:

```
problem.c:18: warning: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’
```

Warnings should not be ignored!